# Is there a way to override the default object printing

Tags: scala, println

I am trying to print an class in scala. Defined below:

```
class Player(balance : Int, player_num :Int ){
    var curHand = new ArrayBuffer[Int]()
    var sum = 0

    def method1()={
        ....
    }
}
```

I want to print to console with something along the lines of:

```
var player1 = new Player(100,1)
println(player1)
```

Is there any way that I can override the toString operator like you can in java in order to achieve this or do I have to make a method like:

```
def print(){
    println("balance " + balance + "Player number" + player_num)
}
```

And call

```
var player1 = new Player(100,1)
player1.print()
```

Answer (score 9):

```
override def toString = "balance " + balance + " Player number " + player_num
```